# Pygame 1.94 for Python 3.7.2 on OS X El Capitan Install Error

Tags: mac, python3

Tried pretty much anything you can find in a search. Can't get around this error. Installed pygame with pip3.

```
$ python3 -m pygame.examples.aliens
pygame 1.9.4
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
2019-03-26 00:52:36.610 Python[86073:400104] 00:52:36.609 WARNING:  140: This application, or a library it uses, is using the deprecated Carbon Component Manager for hosting Audio Units. Support for this will be removed in a future release. Also, this makes the host incompatible with version 3 audio units. Please transition to the API's in AudioComponent.h.
Illegal instruction: 4
```

Python then quits.

Answer (score 0):

Tried again and found this here: https://gist.github.com/connorshea/f539c91f210e72077ca9#gistcomment-2079353

> Blockquote
>   Also, these steps are all no longer necessary. This used to be the preferred method for OS X, but a few months ago Pygame distribution was updated and now all you need to do for all platforms is:

`pip install pygame`